# Pass UIImage and Display in View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

Hi I am saving an image in an NSObject called CaptureManager.  in the .h I set the UIImage properties:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImage *captureImage;
```

and then in the .m set the image

```
       - (void) captureStillImage
{
    AVCaptureConnection *stillImageConnection = [[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillImageConnection
                                                         completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

                                                             if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {
                                                                 NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];

                                                                 captureImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

                                                                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"photoTaken" object:nil userInfo:nil];
                                                             }

                                                             if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManagerStillImageCaptured:)]) {
                                                                 [[self delegate] captureManagerStillImageCaptured:self];
                                                             }
                                                         }];
}
```

Now in my ViewController I am trying to display that Image like so:

```
CaptureManager *captureManager = [[CaptureManager alloc] init];

    UIImage *captureBackgroundImage = captureManager.captureImage;

    UIImageView *captureImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [captureImageView setImage:captureBackgroundImage];
    [self.view addSubview:captureImageView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:captureImageView];
```

Did I do everything correctly?  Is the problem where I have the captureImage set?  Could it be in the captureStillImage method with the completion handler messing this up? Nothing is getting displayed on the screen.  Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: NSLogs are your friend. Add some and see if the captureImage (and other things) are nil or not.

Comment: Where in the view controller are you putting the last code block you posted? It should ideally be in viewDidLoad. If you put it in init or somewhere similar, it won't work, because self.view is still nil at that point.

Comment: Its in ViewDidLoad and I checked to see if captureImage was setting to nil an its not.  Do you see any other things that might be an issue?

Comment: The second code block you posted - where is this located?

Comment: In my .m of the NSObject CaptureManager in a method called captureStillImage

Comment: are you doing the second block on same view controller ?